# Check if clients browser is en-US, en-EG, en-AU, en-GB, en-CA then show English file?

Tags: javascript, localization

```
I have list of languages in array as shown below; I currently have english js file as import and use for localization depending on browser language.
```

// import en from './locale/en';

// List of languages that contains all country languages

```
const list_Of_Languages = [
    'AR-DZ', 'AR-MA',  'AR-TN',  'DA',  'en',  'en-US', 'en-AU', 'en-GB',
    'en-CA', 'en-NZ',  'en-IE',  'fr', ........... ]
```

// and below, I am using to filter the list_Of_Languages and then load my imported en js file for en-US or en

const language_Filter = {
        en,
        'en-US': en,
    };

```
Below is my function to check browser language and then filter through each item inside list_Of_Languages, by default, I am loading en file 

function get_locale() {
  const client = navigator.language;
  const language = list_Of_Languages.filter(item => item.includes(client));
  let [set_Language] = language;
  set_Language = set_Language|| en;
  return language_Filter[set_Language]; 
//If found then I set the language and then return the localization file inside language_Filter 
}
```

//Current problem

If the browser is set to en, en-US then it works fine, but if the browser language is set to other English language then my English file does not load.

Is there a proper and clean way to load my English file if clients browser is set to any en languages. ie..en-CA, en-AU, en-IE

Answer (score 1):

// I modified my get_locale function as below and now it works like charm for any en language setting in client browser;

```
function get_locale() {
const client = navigator.language;
const language = list_Of_Languages.filter(item => item.includes(client));
let set_language;
  if (language.length > 0) {
    set_language = language[0];
    if (client.includes('en')) {
      set_language = 'en';
    }
    set_language= 'en';
  }
  return list_Of_Languages[set_language];
}
```